# How thesy are valid if the coordinate is a right-handed coordinate system?

Tags: vectors, solution-verification

I am trying to understand how $(1),(2) \text{ and } (3)$  are valid if the coordinate is a right-handed coordinate system. The definition of a right-handed coordinate system is a one such that $\overrightarrow{i} \times \overrightarrow{j} =  \overrightarrow{k}$ is valid. To me, to prove that I must compute all possibilities to verify that result. Is there any other method?

$$\overrightarrow{i} \times \overrightarrow{j} =  \overrightarrow{k} \qquad(1)\\ 
  \overrightarrow{j} \times \overrightarrow{k} =  \overrightarrow{i} \qquad(2)\\
  \overrightarrow{k} \times \overrightarrow{i} =  \overrightarrow{j} \qquad(3)$$

I want to very that $(1),(2) \text{ and } (3)$ is valid as long as it is a right-handed coordinate system. what I mean by possibilities is to try all the different ways that $x,y$ and $z$ can be. For example:

[image]   [image]

[image]

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Computing_the_cross_product]

[image]

Comment: How have you defined the cross product? Proofs can only proceed from definitions and axioms (sometimes called by other names such as "postulates").

Comment: Are your two pictures different ways the axes can be? Really? Of course I see that the $z$ axis is pointing up in one case and toward us in the other, but all that means is we have rotated the thing we are looking at (or have moved so that we see it from a different point of view). If we turn the system on the left so the $y$ axis is not going straight off to the right but is angled slightly toward us, do you need to prove the equations again?

Answer (score 1):

$\vec i \times \vec j = \vec k$ in a right-handed *orthonormal* coordinate system. That is, a coordinate system where the three basis vectors are all orthogonal to each other and have length $1$. General coordinate systems may have $\vec i \times \vec j \ne \vec k$. They are called right-handed when $(\vec i \times \vec j) \cdot \vec k > 0$.

I will assume that you are only asking about orthonormal coordinate systems. One identity for the cross product is the ["bac-cab" rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product):
$$\vec a \times (\vec b \times \vec c) = \vec b(\vec a\cdot\vec c) - \vec c(\vec a \cdot \vec b)$$

Since the coordinate system is orthonormal, if $\vec i \times \vec j = \vec k$, then $$\vec j \times \vec k = \vec j \times (\vec i \times \vec j) = \vec i (\vec j \cdot \vec j) - \vec j(\vec j \cdot \vec i) = 1\vec i - 0\vec j = \vec i$$
$$\vec k \times \vec i = \vec k \times (\vec j \times \vec k) = \vec j(\vec k \cdot \vec k) - \vec k (\vec k \cdot \vec j) = 1\vec j - 0\vec k = \vec j$$